# Overriding/extending Django Admin Login page with django-suit

Tags: django, django-suit

I've been working on adding Okta integration to django admin and tried to extend the login page to add a new button (the okta integration itself works fine if a go to /admin/login), but when i do this:

```
{% extends 'admin/login.html' %}
{% load i18n %}




{% block extrastyle %}
   {{ block.super }}
   <style>
       #content-main {
           float: none !important;
       }

       .okta_login_container {
           margin-top: 15px;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
       }
   </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   {{ block.super }}

   <div class="okta_login_container">
       <a href="some-url">Or Login With Okta</a>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Starting the server fails the following error `maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of an object` as it seems to not find the login.html page. overriding other pages like `base.html` work fine.

Other important facts, django-suit is being used and it already overrides the style of the login page.